# Best way to do nothing until things are connected in C#

Tags: c#, database-connection, wait

I was reviewing the code to connect to the DB in one of the applications that I'm working on and I saw this

```
 if (_dbConnection == null)
     _dbConnection = GetConnection();

 while (_dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Connecting)
 {
     //Do Nothing until things are connected.
 }

 if (_dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
     _dbConnection.Open();

 var command = GetCommand(commandType);
 command.Connection = _dbConnection;
 return command;
```

The while loop worries me. Is there a better way to Do Nothing until things are connected?

EDIT:

The connection is gotten as follows

```
private static IDbConnection GetConnection()
{
     return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CoonectionStringName"].ConnectionString);
}
```

Comment: What kind of connection?  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection?

Comment: I would make a timeout as well as putting in the while loop a delay/wait statement so you're not wasting CPU time

Comment: The class of the connection is System.Data.IDbConnection

Comment: Can you use DbConnection instead of IDbConnection?

Comment: I don't really know the difference between those two. I suppose I could.

Comment: Well, if you use IDbConnection you will miss the StateChange events specified by the DbConnection class

Comment: This method looks like it's used in a batch, or it looks like it attempts to optimize the use of an open connection. Where/when is the connection closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though the loop does work and is a valid strategy for waiting on some background operation, other answers seem to miss a key point; you have to let the background operation do some work. Churning through a while loop isn't very productive, but Windows will consider the app's main thread, which is probably what's doing the waiting, to be of high importance, and will spin through the loop hundreds or thousands of times before the background operation ever gets a single clock of CPU time.

To avoid this, use the Thread.Yield() statement to tell the processor to spin through all the other threads awaiting CPU time and come back when they're done. This allows the computer to get some work done while you're waiting on the background process, instead of monopolizing the CPU to spin through a basically empty loop. It's real simple; here's Justin's answer revised:

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;
var endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
var timeOut = false;

while (_dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Connecting)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.CompareTo(endTime) >= 0)
    {
        timeOut = true;
        break;
    }
    Thread.Yield(); //tells the kernel to give other threads some time
}

if (timeOut)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection Timeout");
    // TODO: Handle your time out here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Please note that this works for `DbConnection` and not `IDbConnection`

You can always use the StateChange event of the DbConnection class instead of the while loop.

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.statechange.aspx)

Comment: Just wondering. What if the connection never comes? Will the event never fire?

Comment: @tou: That should be addressed by the Connection Timeout exception handling seperately...

Comment: Would this fully work? What if the same connection was returned? You'd accumulate handlers.

Comment: @Kit: Can  you elaborate on "What if the same connection was returned"?

Comment: Without knowing the implementation of `GetConnection()` (e.g. it could be a static method that caches connections), multiple calls to the code above presumably do `_connection.StateChange += (s, e) => {....}`) which could result in more handlers being invoked on each successive invocation of the called code.

Comment: If the connection is indeed being obtained by a static method then it needs a different analysis altogether...

Comment: The connection it's gotten as follows return `new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringName"].ConnectionString);`

Comment: @Cybernate not sure if this should be its own question but could you explain why it works for 'DbConnection' and not 'IDbConnection'?

Comment: @ace: IDbConnection doesn't expose the StateChange event

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is a web application, the best thing to do is to calculate the duration of time elapsed since you started trying to connect and escape if it exceeds a timeout period. Obviously, throw an exception or handle the situation at that point.

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;
var endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
var timeOut = false;

while (_dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Connecting)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Compare(endTime) >= 0
    {
        timeOut = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (timeOut)
{
    // TODO: Handle your time out here.
}
```

Comment: In this scenario, the while loop is still running and getting a big chunk of processor time.

Answer (score 0):

Hook an handler on the StateChange event.
When the State is Open, do what's needed.

```
            m_SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
            m_SqlConnection.StateChange += new System.Data.StateChangeEventHandler(m_SqlConnection_StateChange);
            m_SqlConnection.Open();



    void m_SqlConnection_StateChange(object sender, System.Data.StateChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (m_SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
            if (m_SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
            {
                Close();
            }
            if (m_SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                Open();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: i would no recommend doing this, as each state change is running on different thread, and it might cause inconsistency when using the connection from different thread,